# Using Geoserver extension CSVDataStore alters existing data store types

Tags: geoserver, geotools, extensions

I am trying to create a custom extension into Geoserver which will act as a datastore.

Being new to GeoServer, I have started with the CSVDataStore tutorial from the GeoTools website.  I have managed to compile the extension and installed it into GeoServer.

The problem is that as soon as I create a new data source based on the new extension, the existing datastores based upon shapefiles change their type to CSV as well.

Anyone experienced this before?

Edit:  I have switched from version 2.11.1 of GeoServer to 2.10.3, and so far I have not seen this behavior. I am not sure yet if this actually is the solution, but I will keep this post updated